# How to include a merged flow in init block of viewmodel

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have written code in the init block that merges 4 flows (`merge(periodStart, periodEnd, selectedPeriodStart, selectedPeriodEnd)`) and outputs a single flow which modifies the value of `_totalAmount`. The problem is that when any of the 4 flows changes, the value of `_totalAmount` does not change. Why isn't the value of _totalAmount changing? There are no errors when running the code.

**The value of _totalAmount does not change**

```kotlin
val _totalAmount = MutableStateFlow(0)
val totalAmount = _totalAmount.asStateFlow()

init{    
        merge(periodStart, periodEnd, selectedPeriodStart, selectedPeriodEnd)
            .map{                
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                    _totalAmount.value = soldItemRepo.getTotalAmountSoldPerPeriod(
                        periodStart.value ?: selectedPeriodStart.value,
                        periodEnd.value ?: selectedPeriodEnd.value
                    ).first()
                }
            }
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
                initialValue = 0
            )
    }
```

I know that if I include the merged flow in the body of the viewmodel as shown below then the value of _totalAmount changes whenever any of the 4 flows changes.

**The value of totalAmount changes**

```kotlin
val totalAmount = merge(periodStart, periodEnd, selectedPeriodStart, selectedPeriodEnd)
        .map{
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                soldItemRepo.getTotalAmountSoldPerPeriod(
                    periodStart.value ?: selectedPeriodStart.value,
                    periodEnd.value ?: selectedPeriodEnd.value
                ).first()
            }
        }.stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
            initialValue = 0)
```

**Reason for asking the question**

I have several variables that depend on `periodStart, periodEnd, selectedPeriodStart, selectedPeriodEnd` ,the 4 flows. I do not want to keep declaring variables as I have done in the case of `totalAmount` above. I would like to have something like the code below

**example**

This is an example of what I would like to achieve.

```
merge(periodStart, periodEnd, selectedPeriodStart, selectedPeriodEnd).map{
val a = {...}
val b = {...}
val c = {...}
...
}
```

If you need any clarification, just ask.

Comment: instead of map, try to collect the flow

Answer (score 0):

I think a better operator for this use case would be the `combine` to combine all the flows' values and use them as you want (to change the value of multiple variables, or other flows). You can read more about the `combine` and the differences between it and `merge` [here](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlins-supercharged-flow-api-combining-and-merging-flows-for-reactive-programming-3aed81f028f0):

I've tested this:

```
    val unitsFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val tensFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val hundredsFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)

    private var a = 0
    private var b = 0
    private var c = 0
    private val exampleFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            combine(unitsFlow, tensFlow, hundredsFlow) { units, tens, hundreds ->
                Triple(units, tens, hundreds) // just concatenate the most recent values (no transformation)
            }.collectLatest { (units, tens, hundreds) ->
                // update several variables (or other flows) using the most recent values
                a = units * 1
                b = (units * 1) + (tens * 10)
                c = (units * 1) + (tens * 10) + (hundreds * 100)
                exampleFlow.update { a + b + (hundreds * 2) }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've used some random variables and flows to illustrate what you wanted. Since you just want to combine several flows without transforming their values, the `combine` part just simply puts them all together in a `Triple`, I'm not sure if you can skip this boilerplate part but [some people have tackled this issue](https://medium.com/@stephenja/combine-flows-for-instant-collection-2ad71d01a6a1).

I've used `collectLatest` but you can use `collect` as well, depending on your use case.

Even though I have tested this and it is working, I don't know if it is a good practice to have this combined flow being collected directly from the `init` block of the ViewModel, maybe put it in a `Job` variable just to make sure you can cancel it easily if needed.

I'd take a deeper look at this part, maybe someone can complement if this is really something to worry about.